# how to create editor templates for Nullable<T> in Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

been trying to find ways to create editor templates for nullable types using razor. I have properties in a LinqToSQL class that are of types Guid and Nullable. when i use `@model Guid?`in the first line of the file `Guid.cshtml`, it always assume Guids as Guid? types. I wanted to create a different editor template for Guid?, but filenames do not accept ? or < or > characters.

please help. thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `@model Nullable<Guid>` rather than `@model Guid?`?

Comment: yes it did, I think it worked better, than I expected. I want it to be a different file/editor template, but  think this will do. Thanks. up vote for you..

Comment: This seems to work if you use e.g. `@model Nullable<Guid>` or just `@model Guid?` (even if you pass in a regular, non-nullable type it seems to cast and work for me), but I would also like to know more about this. Is it possible to create separate templates for regular and nullable types (what would you substitute for ? or < and > in file names)? Or is the recommended style just to make a template for the nullable type to handle both cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess I'll post this as an answer :)

Have you tried `@model Nullable<Guid>` rather than `@model Guid`?

Answer (score 6):

It seems that for nullable value types the intent is to write one display/editor template that handles both nullable and non-nullable types. Here's an excerpt from a [post](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html) by Brad Wilson:

> When searching for the type name, the simple name is used (i.e., Type.Name) without namespace. Also, if the type is Nullable, we search for T (so you’ll get the Boolean template whether you’re using “bool” or “Nullable”). This means if you’re writing templates for value types, you will need to account for whether the value is nullable or not. You can use the IsNullableValueType property of ModelMetadata to determine if the value is nullable. We’ll see an example of this below with the built-in Boolean template.

So, you would use `@model Guid?` in your template and check for nulls.